# Can you use the dropbox api without user athenticate?

Tags: android, user-interface, dropbox-api

Hi I am new in Android and I want know is it possible that you save your dropbox user id and password in constants.Because I don't want the application to ask the user everytime for his password and I need only one account.Is this possible.If yes,then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly,** [**The Dropbox API**](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api) requires the developers to connect to its servers via a sequence of http connections rather than a single connection for security reasons.This way/method of security is known as [**OAuth**](http://oauth.net/).You must have heard the term earlier too.

**Secondly,** It does **not** give you any chance to save username and password in your code for security reasons.Rather,the user is prompted to enter his credentials on an authorization page which is remote to the application (i.e hosted @ dropbox.com).So it is they who handle the authentication/authorization.What you get as pointers an `access token` as a return if the user has been successfully logged in (at the page hosted @ dropbox.com).

When you have this `access token`,**you do not need the user to provide user name and password again**.Instead you just send this `access token` to the server to confirm to the server that this particular user is already authorized.

[**Read this page to know the process in detail**](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api) after marking this as your answer. :smile:

Comment: Thanks man...I will upload into a server because is very important the information.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think you can't.

Please see Android Dropbox Sync Api Example with Login ID and Password from Code and How to login into dropbox from my app.